# Export to CSV out of memory

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

When i write a datatable to a csv file i get an out of memory.
I write the file with the following:

```
if (!filtered)
    {
        string TextExport = DataTableToCSV(datatable, TextSeparator);
        File.WriteAllText(FileName, TextExport);     // Write to the file name selected.                           
    }

private string DataTableToCSV(DataTable datatable, string seperator, bool SuppressDialog = false) 
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Clear();
                sb.Append(@"""");  //start row with " 
                    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; ++i)
                {
                    sb.Append(datatable.Columns[i].ToString());
                    if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                        sb.Append(seperator);
                }
                sb.Append(@"""");   // end row with "
                sb.AppendLine();  //place the header

                foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
                {
                    sb.Append(@""""); //  start row with "
                    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        sb.Append(dr[i].ToString());
                        if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                            sb.Append(seperator);
                    }
                    sb.Append(@""""); // end row with "
                    sb.AppendLine();  //same as : sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                if (SuppressDialog == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Opslaan bestand is gereed.",
                            "Informatie",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.WriteToLog("FOUT", "Exporteren naar CSV bestand is mislukt.");
                Logging.WriteToLog("FOUT", "Melding : ");
                Logging.WriteToLog("FOUT", ex.ToString());
                return "";
            }
        }
```

What i read is that the out of memory apears because i write the file at once. 
How can i write it line by line?

Comment: How big is your DataTable?

Comment: Do not roll your own CSV writing library. Keep in mind, common tasks like that are already solved with far better libraries than you can write on your own. Your business is not to be in the "CSV library" business. Use a pre-existing library, such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What about opening file and append lines directly into the file? If you work with StringBuilder you store all the data into heap which is not good for bigger tables.

Comment: Incidentally, don't explicitly compare to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

While others favor using a library for this, I typically use a List of string and iterate through that to write out large blocks of text.  Caveat - I've only done this with text up to about 35 MB and that still took quite a while to write out.